# QPair initialization

Tags: qt, initialization, qsharedpointer

When I use the following statement,

```
typedef QPair<ItemA, ItemB> test
```

where `ItemB` is a smart pointer.ie typedef `QSharedpointer<Z> ItemB`

When I instantiate test, should I provide initialization values ?
 eg: `test Inst1(0,0);`

Or does `QPair` automatically provide default constructed values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the Qt documentation to be very reliable in such low-level matters. And according to [the QPair documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpair.html), `QPair` has a default constructor with no arguments. (Alternatively, you could just have tried it out...)